# Java REST API adding folders to the project

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm using `jersey` to build a `REST` webservice in `eclipse` everything's work fine but when i added a jar to my project (`webContent/WEB-INF/lib`) and this jar make use of other files. This files are in folders named "configs". When a use this jar in java project i added configs folder to the java project folder and it work okay :)
So how to add folders to the web project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer you just change the working directory.
Run configuration > Arguments > at the bottom you change the working directory